# Extract Base64 data sets from a Swiffy file

Tags: json, html, flash, google-swiffy

Extract Base64 data sets from a Swiffy file

Anyone had experience with this? I had a swf file converted to html and all my images have been converted into base64 in one document.

how can i extract all the images from the html is there a program that can detect base 64 or at least detect multiple images in a html/txt file?

Answer (score 0):

I just extracted from a Swiffy HTML file an MP3 file encoded as base64:

- http://www.casedasole.it/testing/swiffy.html

...like this:

- opened HTML file in Textpad and searched for "base64"
- found this: `"data:audio/mpeg;base64,fQb/4yDAA` [etc., ending with] `CAAIAAgAAA\u003d"` (all between one set of quote marks)
- copied from `fQb/` down to `AAgAAA` (ignored `\u003d"`)
- pasted text into http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html, clicked DECODE
- was prompted with "A binary file can't be displayed inline and you will therefore be prompted to save the output as a file attachment", clicked yes, downloaded file, and added extension .mp3 to the downloaded file
- It plays (in desktop FF and Chrome, with autoplay)! http://www.casedasole.it/testing/swiffy-base64.html

It wasn't an image, but with the same procedure you should be able to spot and extract images. Lemme know.